# PostgreSQL insert query succeeds but then row nowhere to be found

Tags: postgresql

I am at a complete loss.  I perform queries to my data table with an application very rapidly and they seem to be there. However, I have tried to perform a few inserts by hand and although I do not get any errors when I try to select my last insert I cannot find it.

postges 9.3. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any triggers?Maybe you need to refresh?

Comment: Any non-committed transactions?

Comment: I have tried doing it from the CLI as well. This is very strange. Other concurrent queries seem to be working

Comment: You're not committing the transaction.

Comment: May be the insert is inside a "try/catch" structure and the catch was not showing the captured error.

Comment: There is not enough info here for anything other than a guess. Can you update the question with the queries your app is running (incl. any transaction) and the commands you are manually inserting days with.